# Snowflake function parameters with wildcard in where clause

Tags: parameters, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, wildcard

Do  you know why the following function call wont work using wildcards inside the parameter?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ABC("CUSTCODE" VARCHAR, "CUSTNAME" VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE ("CUSTOMER_CODE" VARCHAR, CUSTOMERNAME VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$                                  
   SELECT  CUSTOMER_CODE, CUSTOMERNAME FROM DIM_CUSTOMER
    WHERE  CUSTNAME is null AND CUSTOMER_CODE ILIKE '%CUSTCODE%'
$$;
```

Im getting no errors but also no records found

Seems like its not liking the ilike  '%CUSTCODE%' bit

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have sting quotes `'` inside the code block, but the code block is marked with single quotes. So ether swap to double dollars `$$`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ABC("CUSTCODE" VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE ("CUSTOMER_CODE" VARCHAR, CUSTOMERNAME VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$                                  
   SELECT  CUSTOMER_CODE, CUSTOMERNAME FROM DIM_CUSTOMER
    WHERE  CUSTOMER_CODE ILIKE '%CUSTCODE%'
$$;
```

OR use a double single in the inside..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ABC("CUSTCODE" VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE ("CUSTOMER_CODE" VARCHAR, CUSTOMERNAME VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '                                  
   SELECT  CUSTOMER_CODE, CUSTOMERNAME FROM DIM_CUSTOMER
    WHERE  CUSTOMER_CODE ILIKE ''%CUSTCODE%''
';
```

Comment: a slight change to the function @Simeon Ive added an extra parameter but it didnt return any results for the wildcard in CUSTOMER_CODE

Comment: ah, you are want it to "USE" the variable, not match the word `CUSTCODE`.,..

Comment: yeah lol sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: then you will want: `CUSTOMER_CODE ILIKE ''%' ||CUSTCODE || '%''`

Comment: I believe it might be a good idea to pass wildcard in search i.e. select query using function and inside function code it can just say - WHERE  CUSTOMER_CODE ILIKE CUSTCODE. Usually pattern matching is done in implementation.

Comment: that is also a good solution @Pankaj, that parameter is passed from a webpage and the user should type eg  %1010% atm they are used to typing 1010